# Analyzing the function $f(x) = \sqrt[3]{x^2}(1 - x)$

Tags: calculus

I'm starting Uni soon and I thought I'll try studying calculus 1 on my own to have an edge.

I don't have any math background and I really did try my best to start from the basics and move forward. Anyways, I don't have any figure to help me check my math, and would appreciate the help given to me here:

[taken from a calc 1 math test]

My function:

$\ f(x) = \sqrt[3]{x^2}(1-x) $

Sorry in advance for not knowing the exact English translation.
I was asked a couple of points, and I'd like to know if I got my math right:

1 - This function exists for every $x$ without limitations

2 - the points of contact w/ the graph are $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$

3 - The derivative is $\ f'(x) = \frac{2}{3}x^{(-1/3)} - \frac{5}{3}x^{(2/3)}$

4 - By putting $f'(x) = 0$, I got that $x = 2/5$.

5 - When $x>2/5$, function is negative. When $0<x<2/5$, function is positive. When $x<0$, function is negative.

Function is neither positive nor negative at $2/5$ exactly.

This function has no asymptotes.

Anything correct here or have I gone too deep?

Comment: 2- Shouldn't be (1,0)?

Comment: Correct, my bad. I meant (1,0)

Comment: What about everything else? Find any issues?

Comment: From 4- $$f'(x)=0 \ at \ x=2/5 \ is \ correct, \ you \ could \ say \ that \ x=2/5 \ is \ a \ local \ in \ this \ case \ (global) \ maximum \ with \ the \ value \ f(2/5). And \ everything \ else \ seems \ fine.$$

Comment: One good way to check this kind of thing is with Wolfram Alpha. You can download it on your cellphone. At leats in Brasil, it is cheap, and you only pay once. It is extremely worthwile, it is going to be of much help to you. When you start your university course, you can see there if they provide Wolfram Mathematica software to the students.

Comment: The points of contact in step 2 are called $x$-intercepts.  In step 5, the derivative is positive when $x < 2/5$ (except that it is undefined at $x = 0$), negative when $x > 2/5$, and zero when $x = 2/5$, so the function has a relative maximum at $x = 2/5$ by the First Derivative Test.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure about the English names of these things.